# How do i monitor a job that run for 3 days using python? Any suggested modules to be use here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-upload, subprocess, monitoring

I have a scenario where I need to upload some huge files to a remote location and that runs for 3 days (700+ GB), here, all are command line activity and there is no UI or GUI to monitor it.

How do I do it using some interesting and useful python modules? Any suggested modules would help here.

Currently, i am doing it using the while loop which is not helping much here.

I am running the job inside a screen, once the job completed - checking the md5sum of each of the files and compare it with source & destination. I am using modules os, sys, subprocess, pexpect, time, glob etc.

Comment: Try using celery for this if you can wrap these jobs in python

Comment: This is pretty broad.. could you refine your question to be a bit more specific? simple library / module requests are off topic for S.O.

Comment: The short answer is to include somewhere in your code something that emits a signal / increments a value whenever a smaller piece of work is completed, and in the simplest case, writes it to stdout. slightly more complicated would be to start a thread that keeps track of the progress, and can respond to user requests for status updates (ie: listens on a port for a curl request.. This would allow getting status after sighup on ssh session that initiated the command)